# How do I care for an indoor avocado plant growing in Alaska?

Tags: plant-care

I have an indoor avocado plant in a window on the side of the house that gets the most sun. I live in Alaska. Does the plant need direct sunlight or should i move it somewhere else? It is in a plastic self-watering pot.

Answer (score 2):

My Houseplant Book lists Avocado under 'fun plants' because you can grow them yourself for nothing. This needs repotting annually, prefers a bit of sun if possible, and you should pinch out the tips to promote bushy growth. Water as necessary, but don't leave it sitting in water, once you have potted into something that isn't self watering (if you do), and obviously, don't stand near heat sources. Prefers cooler temperatures in winter when light levels are low. Should make a plant about 3 feet high with large leaves after a few years. As you're not growing it for fruit, whether the sun comes through a window or not is irrelevant - having a brightly lit area with some sun still increases the lux level for the plant.

Answer (score 1):

The Persea Americana, better known by the name of Avocado, belongs to the family Lauraceae, genus and species Persea Gratissima or American. Native of Mexico, is in all respects a tropical plant.

It needs warm / temperate clima, has shallow roots with evergreen and compact foliage. At your latitude, this vine needs the maximum possible sunshine. Direct sun is good only whit open window. The imperfect glass of the windows do not recommend direct light through the close window. Repare it whit a light courtine.

Plastic self watering pot is not the best. Always better pottery making in clay, ensuring breathability.

Avocado cultivars more widespread are characterized by the impossibility of self-fertilization or almost even with hermaphrodite flowers.

Link [here](http://translate.google.es/translate?hl=en&sl=it&u=http://www.agraria.org/coltivazioniarboree/avocado.htm&prev=/search%3Fq%3Davocado%2Bcoltivazione%26hl%3Den&sa=X&ei=wUhOUYbhJpCXhQfjuoG4DQ&ved=0CFgQ7gEwBw)